# Sorting dictionary in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am working on an assignment for school. My professor gave us some code in class and im not sure how the logic of it works.

```
#wdcnt is dictionary with key = "some_string" and value = some_int
v = [wdcnt.values()]
v.sort()
for k in sorted(wdcnt, key = wdcnt.get, reverse = True):
    print(k,wdcnt[k])
```

1. I understand the premise of storing values into a list then sorting them, but why is v not used in the for loop. That line of code seems pointless as v is never used after.
2. wdcnt.get does not have "()" or parameters but still works to return a key value associated with k.

Please help me understand the logic behind this code fragment, thanks.

Note* the assignment is finished and works but to better understand I'd like to get the logic.

Comment: `v` **is** pointless. The code creates a list with one element, sorts it (which has no effect), and then never uses it.

Comment: I love how not only is `v` not used, but actually `v.sort()` is actually not sorting the list of values.

Answer (score 3):

1. `v` Is not used later, you can ignore it, it is indeed useless for the loop
2. The argument `wdcnt.get` is used without parenthesis as it's passing the function as an argument (this is legal in Python):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable (for example, key=str.lower). The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I understand the premise of storing values into a list then sorting them, but why is v not used in the for loop. That line of code seems pointless as v is never used after.

That's right. Like khelwood said, `v` is unused and has no effect.

> 2. wdcnt.get does not have "()" or parameters but still works to return a key value associated with k.

`wdcnt.get` is the [dictionary's .get method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). `wdcnt.get(k)` is another way of saying `wdcnt[k]`.

In detail:

1. `sorted` iterates over the keys of wdcnt.
2. For each key k, `sorted` calls the specified key comparator `wdcnt.get` on it.
3. `wdcnt.get(k)` returns the word count value associated with k. `sorted` then uses those values to determine how to order of the keys.

Comment: *`wdcnt.get(k)` is another way of saying `wdcnt[k]`* -- in this case, okay yes, it happens to be (because what we are passing to it is constrained to be keys that actually exist), but the point about `get` is that if the argument is *not* a valid key then it will return the default value (which itself defaults to `None`) rather than raising a `KeyError`. So it is not strictly true to say that it is just another way of saying `wdcnt[k]`.

Comment: You're right, there's more to it. That's why I linked the .get documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines are unnecessary. It does not need to be used. sorted built-in is a function and one of its parameters is key. The key parameter determines how the array given to the sorted function will be sorted. It is only the name of the function given to the key. () is not used.